# Django rest api not accepting raw data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a user through django rest framwork API.

my views.py

```
class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
 router.register(r'user', views.MyUserViewSet, 'users')
```

User saving is working fine when I submit data as form-data. But when I tried to do that using raw data, am getting the following error.

```
 "groups": [
    "Expected a list of items but got type \"unicode\"."
],
```

Input I am passing as raw data is

```
{
    "password":"12345678",
    "email":"mymail@yopmail.com",
    "groups":"1",
    "first_name":"Arun",
    "last_name":"Joshi"
}
```

I am using postman to test this API.

Comment: Post the data, with value of key "groups" as a list... like, `"groups" : [1, 2]`, primary_keys are integers not strings, remove the quotes for them too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django auth User model, then relationship between User and Groups is many to many. A user can belongs to more than one groups. So you should write a custom create method for your serializer if you want to work it for you with same payload. It will be something like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
def create(self, validated_data):
     user = get_user_model().objects.create(
               email=validated_data.get('email'),
               first_name=validated_data.get('first_name'),
               last_name=validated_data.get('last_name')
            )
     user.set_password('password')
     g = Group.objects.get(id=validated_data.get('group')) 
     g.user_set.add(user)
```

You should set content type as json in postman.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to post the data maybe like this,

```
{
    "password":"12345678",
    "email":"mymail@yopmail.com",
    "groups":[1],
    "first_name":"Arun",
    "last_name":"Joshi"
}
```

Couple things to keep in mind,

- Relation between User and Groups is ManyToMany. So, the serializer accepts the data as a list only. Either you may need to write a custom create method, like @M Hassan suggested, or you just need to post it as a list.
- Primary keys are integer fields, don't post them as strings. If you do, make sure you write appropriate code for catching the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `requests`
set at your headers
`content-type: application/json` 
Like this

```
headers= {'content-type':'application/json'}
data = {
"password":"12345678",
"email":"mymail@yopmail.com",
"groups":"1",
"first_name":"Arun",
"last_name":"Joshi"}
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

For **postman**, just add headers like this 
[image]

Check your project settings also:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
)}
```

Check this also:

```
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer 
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
```

Comment: Already I have set my header as content-type: application/json in postman. Still it is not working. I want to pass data as raw.

Comment: Check the latest solution I have